# No Matching Signature for Operator BETWEEN

Tags: google-bigquery, substring, between

Data describes `Id, Activity Hour and StepTotal`.
`ActivityHour` is defined in the format `YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I am looking to obtain entries between `2016-04-12` AND `2016-05-12`
where the time is between `08:00:00 UTC` AND `15:00:00 UTC`
and the `StepTotal` is less than `50`.
I want the result to be ordered by `Id`.

I thought I should use `substring` to separate date and time - but I am really going wrong somewhere.

Here's what I have:

```sql
SELECT Id, ActivityHour, StepTotal,
SUBSTR(ActivityHour, 11, 23) AS Time,
FROM `dataset` AS Time
WHERE ActivityHour BETWEEN '2016-04-12' AND '2016-05-12'
AND Time BETWEEN '08:00:00 UTC' AND '15:00:00 UTC' 
AND StepTotal < 50
ORDER BY Id, ActivityHour
```

Comment: What is your actual _database_? (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)

Comment: Bigquery - does that answer your Q? I am in bad shape here ..

Answer (score 1):

Are you labeling your table `Time` and then using it to query the actual time between your timepoints? Just because you call it time it doesn't make it time.

Maybe you can use [extract function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions)? Maybe try

```sql
SELECT Id, ActivityHour, StepTotal, SUBSTR(ActivityHour, 11, 23) AS Time, 
FROM dataset 
WHERE ActivityHour BETWEEN '2016-04-12' AND '2016-05-12' 
  AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ActivityHour) BETWEEN 8 AND 15
  AND StepTotal < 50 
ORDER BY Id, ActivityHour
```